# How to configure Hudson to point to local repository instead of central one?

Tags: maven, hudson

I'm a novice in Hudson and need it for automation in building the project. After installing Hudson-3.0.1, i tried building one of the projects manually. I keep getting this error.

> ERROR: Failed to parse POMs
>
> org.apache.maven.project.ProjectBuildingException: Some problems were encountered while processing the POMs:
>
> [FATAL] Non-resolvable parent POM: Could not find artifact com.bnpparibas.parent:bnpparibas-parent:pom:1.0.1 in central (http://repo1.maven.org/maven2) and 'parent.relativePath' points at wrong local POM @ line 41, column 10

I understand that it is looking for the artifact in the central repository rather than in my local. I don't know how to configure hudson to refer to local repository. All my google searches didn't yeild much useful information. Can somebody help me on this?

Answer (score 1):

Redefine "central" repository in your pom:

```
<repositories>
        <repository>
          <snapshots>
            <enabled>false</enabled>
          </snapshots>
          <id>central</id>
          <name>libs-release</name>
          <url>http://localAddress[:localPort]/artifactory/libs-release</url>
        </repository>
        <repository>
          <snapshots />
          <id>snapshots</id>
          <name>libs-snapshot</name>
          <url>http://localAddress[:localPort]/artifactory/libs-snapshot</url>
        </repository>
      </repositories>
      <pluginRepositories>
        <pluginRepository>
          <snapshots>
            <enabled>false</enabled>
          </snapshots>
          <id>central</id>
          <name>plugins-release</name>
          <url>http://localAddress[:localPort]/artifactory/plugins-release</url>
        </pluginRepository>
        <pluginRepository>
          <snapshots />
          <id>snapshots</id>
          <name>plugins-snapshot</name>
          <url>http://localAddress[:localPort]/artifactory/plugins-snapshot</url>
        </pluginRepository>
      </pluginRepositories>
```

Or add more repositories section to your pom

```
  <repository>
      <id>localRepo</id>
      <name>libs-release</name>
      <url>http://localAddress[:localPort]/artifactory/libs-release</url>
    </repository>
```

Or if you have all artifacts in local repo (.m2/repository/) run compilation in off-line mode:
`mvn -o clean install`